# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Joe]
[image: Rowland Shaw]
[image: Vitor Canova]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

Joe has asked to step down. We are very grateful to him for all the time and effort he put in as a moderator.

[row1](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/295/) has graciously stepped up to take over the spot. Welcome to the team!

[image: row1]

---

Vitor has stepped down. We are very grateful to him for all the time and effort he put in as a moderator.

[Indrek](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/1401/) has agreed to step up to take over the spot. Welcome to the team!

[image: Indrek]

---

**Update: September 2017**

[row1](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/295/) has stepped down, but we appreciate all the time he put in as a moderator.

Filling the empty slot is [Thomas](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/979/). Please join me in welcoming him to the team!

[image: Thomas]

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: I think you guys will do a great job. Congratulations and get to work!

Comment: Just notice Joe step down and @row1 became mod. Welcome aboard.

Comment: @VitorCanova yeah I have been lurking around as a mod :) Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: Sorry pals. I'm not have been active lately (year) and thing this diamond will be more useful in @Indrek hands.

Comment: @VitorCanova Thanks, I hope I'll be able to help the community grow and evolve :)

Comment: Welcome aboard @Thomas !

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Anna for the nomination.

Good to see that our community is growing and now some of us can help more to increase the quality of our Q&A.

Congratulations to every moderator. We deserve and need to show more work now. ;)